# Storing xml data on django Model

Tags: python, xml, django

I am trying to store XML file data from msn weather service on my models as you can see the code below

```
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = "This will update the weather reports by fetching xml from msn and storing data"

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        tree = ElementTree()
        path = urllib2.urlopen('http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?src=vista&weadegreetype=C&culture=en-US&wealocations=wc:sfxx0010')
        tree = ET.parse(path)
        root = tree.getroot()
        xmllist=[]
        a = 0
        for i in root:
            xmllist = xmllist + [XmlDictConfig(i)]
        for i in xmllist:
            date = fixdate(i['date']) #Date, date=date heading=i['heading']
            a = Forecast.objects.create(mintemp=i['low'] ,maxtemp=i['high'],wind=i['wind'],rain=i['precipitation'],date=date)
            a.save()
            print "Data Updated"
```

I get a key error
KeyError: 'date'

Comment: *Where* did you get a key error? What is the traceback?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Basically am getting a key error:

Comment: This is the error as it comes  Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home2/saywow/bubi11/list/management/commands/weather.py", line 120, in handle_noargs
    date = fixdate(i['date']) #Date, date=date heading=i['heading']
KeyError: 'date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to work that out, it took one sleepless night but it was as simple as the code below

```py
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = "This will update the weather reports by fetching xml from msn and storing data"
    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        path = urllib2.urlopen('http://weather.service.msn.com/data.aspx?src=vista&weadegreetype=C&culture=en-US&wealocations=wc:sfxx0010')
        tree = ET.parse(path)
        root = tree.getroot()
        x = root.findall('*/forecast')
        for forecast in x:
            date = forecast.get('date') #Date, date=date heading=i['heading'], ,maxtemp=i['high'],wind=i['wind'],rain=i['precipitation']
            maxtemp = forecast.get('high')
            wind = forecast.get('skytextday')
            rain = forecast.get('precip')
        mintemp = forecast.get('low')
            a = Forecast.objects.create(mintemp=mintemp, maxtemp=maxtemp, date=date, wind=wind, rain=rain)
            a.save()
            print "Data Updated Thank You"
```